# Android TextWatcher StackOverflow error

Tags: android, android-edittext, stack-overflow, textwatcher

I ALREADY know there are many questions asking the same thing, but they don't work for me. Here is the code (I use the code to color a text part in a EditText) -

```
et_note.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (textCC.contains("sample_text")) {
            String syntaxText = "sample_text";
            int ofe = textCC.indexOf(syntaxText, 0);
            int nextOfe = textCC.indexOf(syntaxText, ofe);
            for (int ofs = 0; ofs < textCC.length() && ofe != -1 && nextOfe != -1; ofs = nextOfe + 1) {
                ofe = textCC.indexOf(syntaxText, ofs);
                nextOfe = textCC.indexOf(syntaxText, ofe + 1);
                if (ofe == -1 || nextOfe == -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(et_note.getText());
                    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), ofe, nextOfe + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    et_note.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                }
            }
        }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

It gives Stack Overflow error.

**Answers that work but are not suitable -**

1) Add `et_note.removeTextChangedListener(this)` before the code and add `et_note.addTextChangedListener(this)` after the code - This one works but NOT properly and the app becomes VERY slow.

Any other ways that will help me? Thanks.

Comment: For one, do not call `setText()` on the watched `EditText`. Instead of creating a new `Spannable` based on what is in the `EditText`, just use the `Spannable` that you get back from `getText()`, and set your span on it.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I do it? I mean _use the Spannable that you get back from getText(), and set your span on it_.

Comment: `et_note` appears to be an `EditText`. [The `getText()` method on `EditText` returns an `Editable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29). [`Editable` is a sub-interface of `Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html). [`setSpan()` is a method defined on `Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Hence, you can call `setSpan()` on the object returned by `et_note.getText()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare, I found the answer. Just posting this answer to help others. This solved my problem - 

 Instead of this,

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(et_note.getText());
                WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), ofe, nextOfe + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                et_note.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I used this -

```
et_note.getText().setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), ofe, nextOfe + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```